# What are the paths for this adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, adjacency-matrix

This is the matrix
  0 1 2 3
0(1 1 1 0 )
1(1 0 1 0 )
2(1 1 0 1 )
3(0 0 1 1 )

The question is provide the matrix that represents the numbers of paths of length 3 between any two vertices. Your solution to this should indicate there are six paths of length three from vertex 0 to vertex 2. one of them is <(0,0)(0,1)(1,2)> list the other 5.

I don't understand how to find the 6 paths, this is because I dont see how there can be 6 paths, all paths I could find that were length 3 was 6 paths, and not all of them were from vertex 0 to 2

Answer (score 1):

With rows and columns corresponding to vertices 0, 1, 2, 3, the adjacency matrix we're told is this:
$$ A =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right] 
$$
The $i,j$ entry of A is 1 if there is a **path of length 1** between vertex $i$ and vertex $j$.

To count paths of length 3, we must look at $A^3$, the cube of the adjacency matrix. It's
$$ A^3 =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
   7 &  5 &  6 &  3 \\
   5 &  3 &  5 &  2\\
   6 &  5 &  4 &  4\\
   3 &  2 &  4 &  3
\end{array}\right] 
$$
Note that the 0,2 entry is 6.  So there are 6 paths of length 2 from vertex 0 to vertex 2.  Note that some of these paths, such as the example given in the question, involve self-loops  at one of the vertices.

Here are the paths of length 2 from vertex 0 to vertex 2:

<(0,0)(0,0)(0,2)> and
<(0,0)(0,1)(1,2)>

<(0,1)(1,0)(0,2)>

<(0,2)(2,0)(0,2)> and
<(0,2)(2,1)(1,2)> and
<(0,2)(2,3)(3,2)>